# nohup with at the end <&-

Tags: io-redirection, nohup

```
nohup grunt server:debug >grunt.out 2>&1 <&- &
```

I have a nohup command that ends with `<&-` .
What does this direction do? Can some explain with pointers. I did search google for examples, but could not find one which explained about `<&-` and is this really required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather search through manual pages (`man bash` is your friend). Such special characters are hard to find in google. Basically you end up with this section:

> **Duplicating File Descriptors**
>
> The redirection operator
>
> ```
> [n]<&word
> ```
>
> is used to duplicate input file descriptors.  If `word` expands to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by `n` is made to be a copy of that file descriptor.  If the digits  in  `word`  do not  specify  a file descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs.  **If word evaluates to `-`, file descriptor `n` is closed.  If `n` is not specified, the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.**

So in the other words, `<&-` means, that it basically closes `stdin`, so the program running under `nohop` really can not read anything from there.

Answer (score 1):

May be this list helps:

**<&**(Digit)   Duplicates standard input from the file descriptor specified by the Digit parameter

**>&**(Digit)  Duplicates standard output in the file descriptor specified by the Digit parameter

**<&-**     Closes standard input

**>&-**     Closes standard output